# Load an XML file with a variable file name to be transformed with XSL

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xslt

I am looking to run the following in Excel VBA:

```
Dim xmldoc As Object, xsldoc As Object, newdoc As Object

Set xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set xsldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set newdoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

' LOAD XML
xmldoc.async = False
xmldoc.Load ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Original.xml"  

' LOAD XSL
xsldoc.async = False
xsldoc.Load ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\XSLT_File.xsl"

' TRANSFORM
xmldoc.transformNodeToObject xsldoc, newdoc
newdoc.Save ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Output.xml"
```

I am running this in the same code, but after, the step whereas the original XML is exported

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAsXMLData xmlDirName & fileName & ".xml", objMapToExport
```

Where “filename” is a time-stamp of when the save is performed.

How can I rewrite the LOAD XML VBA so it knows to load the XML that was just created in the code?

Comment: Try assigning the time stamp to a variable before exporting the file. It might be a few milliseconds out time wise. Otherwise maybe use `Set SomeVariable = ActiveWorkBook.SaveAs............` then see it you can get it from the variable

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen great idea. I will give it a try.

Comment: This eerily looks familiar...but why not just pass the XML file name as a parameter to the function/subroutine where this XSLT processing resides?

Comment: @Parfait you are not crazy. You provided me the code above that is why it looks familiar. I was just getting stumped with how to configure it when the file name is not static. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass the exported XML file name as a parameter to the subroutine or function running the XSLT transformation assuming both procedures are behind same sheet or same module.

```
Public Sub XMLExport()
    ...rest of code...

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAsXMLData xmlDirName & fileName & ".xml", objMapToExport

    Call XSLTransformation(xmlDirName & fileName & ".xml")   

End Sub


Public Sub XSLTransformation(strfile As String)
   Dim xmldoc As Object, xsldoc As Object, newdoc As Object

   Set xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
   Set xsldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
   Set newdoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

   ' LOAD XML
   xmldoc.async = False
   xmldoc.Load strfile   ' <------  CHANGE HERE

   ' LOAD XSL
   xsldoc.async = False
   xsldoc.Load ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\XSLT_File.xsl"

   ' TRANSFORM
   xmldoc.transformNodeToObject xsldoc, newdoc
   newdoc.Save ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Output.xml"
End Sub
```